# $elemMatch equivalient for nested array as com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

i wrote the following filter in the mongodb console

```
"outers":{"$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{y:{$gt : 48.99}}}}
```

what would be the bson equivalent? i got this:

```
elemMatch("outers", elemMatch("y", gt("y", 48.99)))
```

but it feels wrong, because of the duplicate y-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Filters.elemMatch("outers", Filters.lt("y", 48.99))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elemMatch("outers", eq("$elemMatch", lt("y", 48.99)))
```

did the trick